# In-memory lookup from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an AWS API gateway that forwards the request to AWS lambda which the calls AWS personalize get real-time recommendations.

The API gateway receives a hashed customer email in the payload from the client (website). This hashed customer email id need to be resolved into an internal customer id(which is used to train personalization model) so that lambda can invoke the personalize service with this customer ID.
I was planning to use AWS Elasticache redis cluster to do hashed customer email>customer-id  lookup. Reading the documentation found out that the elasticache cluster is deployed in a VPC.

- So inorder for lambda to access the elasticache redis cluster - does lambda need to be run attached to this VPC ?
- I have read that Lambda creates a network interface to connect to vpc and it takes up to few minutes. So in that case I will not be able to use this approach to serve API requests. Is my understanding correct?
- Is there any better approache to do in-memory lookup from AWS lambda ? I need to keep the API gateway latency below 300ms and scale to 3000 requests per minute

Answer (score 2):

> So inorder for lambda to access the elasticache redis cluster - does
> lambda need to be run attached to this VPC

Yes it would have to be in the VPC to access ElastiCache.

> I have read that Lambda creates a network interface to connect to vpc
> and it takes up to few minutes. So in that case I will not be able to
> use this approach to serve API requests. Is my understanding correct?

The cold-start time for Lambda in a VPC [is much improved now](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/).